# Display the category names for the current post, but exclude one ID

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

Im trying to display the current post category name for a custom post types' taxonomy, but exclude one of the categories. I see different solutions in StackOverflow, but I can't seem to get any of them to work for me. Below is the code I am using, which works great, but I don't know how to exclude one ID using it.

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'press_category' ); 
                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                        $term_link = get_term_link( $term, 'press_category' );
                        if( is_wp_error( $term_link ) )
                        continue;
                    echo  $term->name ;
                    } 
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'press_category');
foreach ($terms as $term)
{
    $term_link = get_term_link($term, 'press_category');
    if (is_wp_error($term_link)) continue;
    if ($term->term_id != 222)
    {
        echo $term->name;
    }
}
?>
```

Change 222 in this line to your taxonomy id for exclude

> $term->term_id != 222